# Python: pygame - Trying to import an image into pygame using python

Tags: python, pygame

So,  I've been working on my first game for a while now and I have gotten stuck in the same place, trying to add an image to the apple that the snake is supposed to collect and it isn't working. It's giving me this error: TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not list. My code is below, it's messy because this is my first game, please don't judge.

```
import pygame
import sys
import time
import random
import collections
import itertools
import os
import pygame.mixer



pygame.init()                                     
pygame.mixer.init() 


apple = [pygame.image.load('New Piskel.png')]

#colect_1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Beep_Short.mp3")


def main():
    """Snake v 1.59"""
    score = 0  # Initial score
    speed = pygame.time.Clock()
    direction = "R"  # Initial direction
    snake_position = collections.deque([100, 50])  # Initial snake position
    snake_body = collections.deque([[100, 50], [90, 50], [100, 50]])  # Initial snake body
    # It places the food randomly, excluding the border
    food_position = [random.randrange(1, 72) * 10, random.randrange(1, 46) * 10]
    food_spawn = True
    # Will define the colors
    white = pygame.Color("white")
    red = pygame.Color("red")
    green = pygame.Color("green")
    black = pygame.Color("black")
    orange = pygame.Color("red")
    grey = pygame.Color("light grey")
    # Game surface
    player_screen = pygame.display.set_mode((720, 460))  # Set screen size
    pygame.display.set_caption("Snake v.1.38")  # Set screen title and version

    def initializer():
        """ Checks the mistakes, and closes the program if it does while
        printing on the console how many bugs it has, also initializes
        the mixers, and game """
        pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 1, 512)
        pygame.mixer.init()
        bugs = pygame.init()
        if bugs[1] > 0:
            print("There are", bugs[1], "bugs! quiting.....")
            time.sleep(3)
            sys.exit("Closing program")
        else:
            print("The game was initialized")

    def game_sound(s):
        """ Include the game sfx and music"""
        if s == 0:
            directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, "background.ogg")
            pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
        elif s == 1:
            directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, "eating.wav")
        elif s == 2:
            directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(sys.argv[0]))
            full_path = os.path.join(directory, "game-over.wav")

    def start_screen():
        """ The beggining screen that you see at the beginning of the game
             and the ene if you die"""
        player_screen.fill(white)
        start1_font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 44)
        start2_font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 20)
        start1_surface = start1_font1.render("Welcome To Snake! (A pygame remake.)", True, black)
        start2_surface = start2_font2.render("Press 'space' to start", True, black)
        start1_position = start1_surface.get_rect()
        start1_position.midtop = (360, 100)
        start2_position = start2_surface.get_rect()
        start2_position.midtop = (360, 150)
        player_screen.blit(start1_surface, start1_position)
        player_screen.blit(start2_surface, start2_position)
        pygame.display.flip()


    def you_lose():
        """ When the players loses, it will show a red message in times new
         roman font with 44 px size in a rectangle box"""
        font_game_over = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 44)
        start2_font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 20)
        game_over_surface = font_game_over.render("Game Over!", True, red)
        start2_surface = start2_font2.render("Press 'o' to restart", True, black)
        game_over_position = game_over_surface.get_rect()
        game_over_position.midtop = (360, 15)
        start2_position = start2_surface.get_rect()
        start2_position.midtop = (360, 150)
        player_screen.blit(game_over_surface, game_over_position)
        player_screen.blit(start2_surface, start2_position)
        scoring()
        pygame.display.flip()  # Updates the screen, so it doesnt freeze

    def pause_menu():
        """It displays the pause menu"""
        player_screen.fill(white)
        pause1_font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 44)
        pause2_font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 20)
        pause3_font3 = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 20)
        pause1_surface = pause1_font1.render("Paused!", True, black)
        pause2_surface = pause2_font2.render("Press 'space' to unpause!", True, black)
        pause3_surface = pause3_font3.render("press 'o' to restart", True, black)
        pause1_position = pause1_surface.get_rect()
        pause1_position.midtop = (360, 90)
        pause2_position = pause2_surface.get_rect()
        pause2_position.midtop = (360, 170)
        pause3_position = pause3_surface.get_rect()
        pause3_position.midtop = (360, 220)
        player_screen.blit(pause1_surface, pause1_position)
        player_screen.blit(pause2_surface, pause2_position)
        player_screen.blit(pause3_surface, pause3_position)
        pygame.display.flip()

    def quiting():
        """ When this function is called, it will wait 3 seconds and exit"""
        time.sleep(1)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    def scoring():
        """ It will shows the score after the game over in times new
        roman font with 16px size and black color in a rectangle box"""
        score_font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 16)
        score_surface = score_font.render("Score : {}".format(score), True, black)
        score_position = score_surface.get_rect()
        score_position.midtop = (360, 80)
        player_screen.blit(score_surface, score_position)

    def ingame_scoring():
        """ It will shows the score after the game over in times new
        roman font with 16px size and black color in a rectangle box"""
        iscore_font = pygame.font.SysFont("times new roman", 16)
        iscore_surface = iscore_font.render("Score : {}".format(score), True, black)
        iscore_position = iscore_surface.get_rect()
        iscore_position.midtop = (360, 15)
        player_screen.blit(iscore_surface, iscore_position)



    initializer()
    pygame.display.flip()
    paused = False
    run = True
    if run == True:
        start_screen()
        paused = not paused

    #if run == True:
       #pygame.mixer.Sound.play(bg_music)


    while True:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                quiting()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:  # Pausing/ unpausing
                    paused = not paused
                    if paused:
                        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                        pause_menu()

                    else:
                        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()


                # Choose direction by user input, block opposite directions
                key_right = event.key in (pygame.K_RIGHT, pygame.K_d)
                key_left = event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_a)
                key_down = event.key in (pygame.K_DOWN, pygame.K_s)
                key_up = event.key in (pygame.K_UP, pygame.K_w)
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    paused = not paused
                    if paused:
                        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
                        pause_menu()
                if keys[pygame.K_o]:
                    main()
                if key_right and direction != "L":
                    direction = "R"
                elif key_left and direction != "R":
                    direction = "L"
                elif key_down and direction != "U":
                    direction = "D"
                elif key_up and direction != "D":
                    direction = "U"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    quiting()  # It will quit when esc is pressed

        # Simulates the snake movement(together with snake_body_pop)
        if not paused:
            if direction == "R":
                snake_position[0] += 10
            elif direction == "L":
                snake_position[0] -= 10
            elif direction == "D":
                snake_position[1] += 10
            elif direction == "U":
                snake_position[1] -= 10
            # Body mechanics
            snake_body.appendleft(list(snake_position))
            if snake_position == collections.deque(food_position):
                score += 1  # Every food taken will raise the score by 1
                food_spawn = False  # It removes the food from the board
            else:
                # If the food is taken it will not remove the last body piece(raising snakes size)
                snake_body.pop()
            if food_spawn is False:  # When a food is taken it will respawn randomly
                food_position = [random.randrange(1, 72) * 10, random.randrange(1, 46) * 10]
            food_spawn = True  # It will set the food to True again, to keep the cycle
            # Drawing
            player_screen.fill(grey)  # Set the background to grey
            for position in snake_body:  # Snake representation on the screen
                pygame.draw.rect(player_screen, green, pygame.Rect(position[0], position[1], 10, 10))
            # Food representation on the screen
            player_screen.blit(apple,(food_position[0], food_position[1], 10, 10))
            if snake_position[0] not in range(0, 711) or snake_position[1] not in range(0, 451):
                you_lose()
                paused = True # Game over when the Snake hit a wall
            for block in itertools.islice(snake_body, 1, None):
                if snake_position == collections.deque(block):
                    you_lose()
                    paused = True # Game over when the Snake hits itself
            pygame.display.flip()  # It constantly updates the screen
            speed.tick(10)  # It sets the speed to a playable value


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Why is apple saved as a list, and not `apple = pygame.image.load('New Piskel.png')`?

Answer (score 0):

`apple = []` generates an empty list and `apple = [pygame.image.load('New Piskel.png')]` generates a list with one element.

When you want to `blit` the apple then you have to get the 1st element of the list (`apple[0]`):

```py
player_screen.blit(apple[0], (food_position[0], food_position[1], 10, 10))
```

Anyway, it seems that you don't need a list at all. If `apple` is an instance of `pygame.Surface` rather than a list:

```py
apple = pygame.image.load('New Piskel.png')
```

then `apply` can be `blit` directly:

```py
player_screen.blit(apple, (food_position[0], food_position[1], 10, 10))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I did what you recommended and now its giving me another error: TypeError: 'pygame.Surface' object is not callable.